# Laravel Broadcasting with Soketi listening to channel via Echo is not working

Tags: laravel, vue.js, websocket, laravel-echo, laravel-websockets

I'm using Laravel Broadcasting with Soketi and I'm trying to listen to the jobs channel and JobFailedEvent. So here is my code.

```html
class JobFailedEvent implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public $jobName;
    public $errorMessage;
    public function __construct($jobName, $errorMessage)
    {
        $this->jobName = $jobName;
        $this->errorMessage = $errorMessage;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return array<int, \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel>
     */
    public function broadcastOn(): array
    {
        return [
            new Channel('jobs'),
        ];
    }
}
```

This is my bootstrap.js

```html
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher;


window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "pusher",
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost:
        import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ??
        `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
});
```

and lastly the Vue component where I'm trying to listen to

```html
const echo = ref();

echo.value = new Echo({
    broadcaster: "pusher",
    key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
    wsHost:
        import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ??
        `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
    wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
    wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
    forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
    enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
});

echo.value.channel('jobs').listen('JobFailedEvent', (e) => {
    console.log('Job failed:', e);

});
```

Apparently even after the event is done, the listen in Vue component is never called even if I received the payload
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Listen for event 'App\Events\JobFailedEvent':

```
echo.value.channel('jobs').listen('App\\Events\\JobFailedEvent', (e) => { console.log('Job failed:', e); });
```